# Visual Studio 2013 changed the behavior of Window.CloseToolWindow. I need the previous behavior somehow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013

In VS2010 and VS2012 at least, Window.CloseToolWindow would do just that. If it was invoked while a text file had focus, it did nothing. It seems that in VS2013 it will now close the text file. This sadly breaks my workflow in an AutoHotkey macro. Does anyone have any idea of a Visual Studio command that would have the old behavior? One default shortcut is Shift + Esc if you want to try this out easily.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The good news - this is fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

Answer (score 1):

What's even more strange is the way <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> "closes" the text file. It just hides it, but doesn't close it as the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does.

It sadly seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Heya TigerShark, thanks for your interest! I hope it's a bug, then it might get fixed. I'm curious though, how are you seeing a difference between <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>? They seem to do the same thing for me.

Comment: @Programmer Paul - I have put off commenting on this because I wanted to find an answer and come with that.  Sadly, I have not.  I will add that I see what TigerShark is saying - if you "close" a code editor window with ctrl+esc and pop it open again, the undo stack for actions you have taken is still intact.  If you close it with ctrl+F4, this is not the case.

Comment: Interesting timing on the comments! I literally met a guy on the Visual Studio team at Microsoft yesterday. I jokingly asked if he could fix a few things for me. I said he could file bug reports. I might have to show this one to him. In my case, the solution I've come up with is the addon Layouts O Rama. It's way better than the hokey pokey mess I was doing with my AutoHotkey script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but one workaround that will work in some, but certainly not all, situations is that with ReSharper, ctrl+shift+F4 will close a ReSharper tool window tab.  If there is only one tab, it will close the window and also exhibits the correct behavior of not closing a code editor window.  I'm sorry I don't have a better answer.  I too lament this bug and want the real fix from M$.